# I need to center the navigation bar

Tags: css, nav, navigationbar

I'm lost... I tried the other answers given in the questions with no results.

Here, my CCS:

```
ul.nav { padding-top: 5px; font-family: 'OFL Sorts Mill Goudy TT', Georgia, serif; float: left; }
ul.nav li { margin-left: 7px; }
    ul.nav a { font-size: 17px; color: #918f8f; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; padding: 15px 6px 18px; }
    ul.nav a:hover { color: #000000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; }
```

How can i center my navigation bar?

Comment: Remove `float: left;`, assign fixed `width` to `ul.nav` and use `margin: auto;`

Answer (score 1):

You can give your UL a fixed width and center like this:

```
ul.nav {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If this navigation isn't supposed to be a sidebar, then remove the float: left;

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `float:left;`
- add a `width.`
- add `margin:0 auto;`

`
css

```
ul.nav {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: 'OFL Sorts Mill Goudy TT', Georgia, serif;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body{ text-align:center;}
{And rest of your code...}
```

and it will be in center.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float` first of all - it will throw your list over to the left of the screen. Then, you have two options:

**Give the List a fixed width, then use `margin:0 auto`.**

```
ul.nav {
    width: 40em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This if fine if you will always have a set amount of links in your nav bar. Not so useful if this changes frequently, or even dynamically. I would prefer the following solution, although an additional bit of markup is required

**Use a wrapping element, styled `display:table`**

The HTML:

```
<nav class="my-class" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then your CSS:

```
.my-class {
    display: table; /*centers its contents*/
    width: 100%; /*make sure it doesn't collapse*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    whatever /*just don't use text align!*/
}
```

Now it doesnt matter how much you put in that list, it will always center for you.